# how to solve error 1450 on android futronic fingerprint scanner demo?

Tags: android, fingerprint, usb-hostcontroller

Don't know if this the right place to ask this question but desperately need all the help I can get.

I have an android device with integrated Futronic fingerprint scanner. I have been able to communicate with the scanner and gain access to it using the usb host mode.

I have the below log on the Logcat showing am able to communicate with the scanner

```
I/FUTRONICFTR_J: Open device: UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/054,mVendorId=5265,mProductId=32,mClass=0,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mManufacturerName=Futronic Technology Company Ltd.,mProductName=Futronic Fingerprint Scanner 2.0,mVersion=2.0,mSerialNumber=FS00212726,mConfigurations=[
UsbConfiguration[mId=1,mName=null,mAttributes=128,mMaxPower=75,mInterfaces=[
UsbInterface[mId=0,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=null,mClass=255,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mEndpoints=[
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=1,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=0]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=130,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=0]]]]
```

But when i try to capture, i get `1450` error code coming from the .so libs. The error happened after calling this code in the AnsiLibSDK class

```
public native boolean OpenDeviceCtx(final Object object);
```

While I have all the .so files in my jinLib folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shared Libraries `.so` files need access to the storage. Storage Permission must be granted to the app for it to work.

Granted Permission and the error goes away!